# getText displaying property name instead of value

Tags: jsp, struts2

I've been starting to learn Struts 2 over the past week or so and have gotten stumped on an example using the TextProvider interface.  I have a simple class (TextExampleAction.java) that just returns the SUCCESS string.  Here is the source of the action class:

```
package com.packt.s2wad.ch03.i18n;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TextExampleAction extends ActionSupport implements TextInterface {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TextExampleAction.class);
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        log.debug(getText("from.class.props"));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And here is the source of the JSP file (text-example.jsp):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<body>
   <dl>
       <dt>From TextExampleAction.properties via property tag, using getText(...)</dt>
       <dd><s:property value="getText('from.class.props')"/></dd>
   </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

My properties file is named the same as my Java class (TextExampleAction.properties) and is located in the same package.  Here is the contents of that file:

> from.class.props=Hello from TextExample.properties!

When I view the page, here is what is displayed:

> From TextExampleAction.properties via property tag, using getText(...) 
>              from.class.props

So I'm just trying to figure out why it's returning a null value for that property...

EDIT:

[image: here is the output of the debug tag]

Comment: I just tried it but it's still not displaying the property value.

Comment: strange...its working for me i just cross checked it.this is the entry in my jsp `<s:property value="%{getText('from.class.props')}"/>`

Comment: I added output from the debug tag...

Comment: on curious note can you show Action class?

Comment: just cross check have you named the property file correctly and have placed the file at correct location.Just your example should work even you need not to use `%{}` notation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6853/discussion-between-umesh-awasthi-and-brian)

Comment: The properties file has the same base name as my action class with the ".properties" extension and both files are within the com.packt.s2wad.ch03.i18n package.  I've also double-checked the property name and it's the same as what I'm referencing in my JSP file.  It's really weird.

Comment: Does the debug output show the correct value? How are you deploying?

Comment: It's version 2.3.1.  No, the value is not being output to the log, either.  I'm using a build script to package everything up into a WAR file and then deploying on Tomcat 7.

Comment: @Brian (Make sure you use the `@` to direct comments otherwise we're not notified :) Are you sure the resource file is on the classpath in the war file? Can you put the project up on github/etc? (Not the dependencies/compilation output, just the important stuff.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I'm pretty sure as the files are being copied over to WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: @DaveNewton: i even tried the code posted above on my local machine and it worked without any problem.so my doubt is either some typo or might be wrong placement of files

Comment: @Brian i am with opinion of Dave, place your code on some place den can be looked at what might be the issue

Comment: @DaveNewton Here is the URL for my github repo: https://github.com/brilewis/Basic_Struts2_Ant

Comment: @Brian See updated answer; there's a lot missing.

Comment: @Brian Also, what is `TextInterface`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue under Struts 2.3.1.

- Make sure property and class file are named `TextExampleAction` (with correct extension).
- Make sure the property file is in the exact same package hierarchy in the war file itself.

For example, here's my Maven output:

```
s231_01_war_exploded
        |-- index.jsp
        `-- WEB-INF
            |-- classes
            |   |-- actions
            |   |   |-- TextExampleAction.class
            |   |   `-- TextExampleAction.properties
            |   |-- log4j.properties
            |   `-- struts.xml
            |-- jsp
            |   `-- test.jsp
            |-- lib
            |   `-- (all the libs)
            `-- web.xml
```

This works as expected.

---

*Edit after looking at project*

Your S2 config file, `struts.xml`, isn't being deployed.

Also, as it stands in the repo, you are not running any requests through your own actions, only the default S2 forwarding action--you won't get any of your packaged I18N files picked up because they don't exist in the default action's package.

I really recommend not doing this via Ant, but by using Maven as suggested in the book, although in this case the only thing missing is the `struts.xml` file. As your `build.xml` currently stands, put `struts.xml` at the root of your source directory.

Comment: I think it was mainly due to the struts.xml location because after creating a new project using the struts2-blank.war getText() was working correctly.

Comment: @Brian Gotcha. Doing all this via Ant is pretty sketchy unless you're using something like Ivy for dependency management, btw--too easy to miss a dependency. For simple use cases, you shouldn't have to mess with Maven too much--IMO might as well use it.

Comment: Is it just a coincidence or did you happen to write the AS2 Web App Development book (http://www.amazon.com/Apache-Struts-Web-Application-Development/dp/1847193390)?

Comment: @Brian That was me. I apologize for their editing and indexing--it is pretty awful :/